# Why is Perl script asking for 'global declaration' when I declare something in for loop?

Tags: perl, error-handling, global-variables

I am reading `$digit` from *infile* and want to print it to *outfile*. But the Perl script is giving an error saying 'Global symbol "$digit" requires explicit package name'. But, if I do declare it globally , `$digit=''`, then the this value is printed to the *outfile* instead of the value extracted/read from *infile*. Any suggestions as to what should be done?

This how I am doing it:

```
    my $digit=''; 
    open (DATA, "</usr/infile") || die "cant open infile\n"; #file from digit has to read

    while (<DATA>){
        ($digit)= $_=~ /\s9\s(\d+)/; #regex to capture digit '234' from ' 9 234'
        if ($digit ne ""){
        print "digit is $digit\n"; # this prints fine
        }
    }

    open (FILE, ">/usr/outfile") || die "cant open outfile\n"; #file to which digit has to be finally written
    print FILE "9   $digit"; #$digit takes in the value declared globally i.e. ''

    close(DATA);
    close (FILE);
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please include $! in your die message. eg: die "/usr/infile:$!"

Comment: The `DATA` filehandle is special. Don't break the reasonable assumptions of people who know Perl. Besides, you should be using lexical filehandles anyway. So, use `open my $data ...`

Comment: @Sinan: Will that help with my question?

Comment: Please show us inputs and outputs demonstrating the problem.

In your latest edit, there is only one variable `$digit`, lexically scoped to cover the whole script (more or less) and the `while` loop.

What's happening, then, is that the final line of input file `/usr/infile` does not match your regex, thus setting `$digit` to `undef`, which looks a lot like the blank string when you print it.  :)

Comment: @shubster I don't know if that will help with your current question but it sure will cut the amount of cruft one has to read through to be able to help you. Help others help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$digit` is scoped within the while loop and then you are trying to access it outside it with the line:

```
print FILE "9   $digit";
```

You must declare it outside the while loop for this to be visible by that line.

Or better yet just open your outfile before you loop and write the digit to the outfile within the loop and keep your `$digit` variable scoped within the loop.

If you only want the last instance that matches your regex then:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open (DATA, "infile.txt")  || die("cant open infile\n");   

my $digit = "";
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/\s9\s(\d+)/) #regex to capture digit '234' from ' 9 234' 
    {
       print "Found digit is $1\n"; # 
       $digit = $1;
    }
}
close(DATA);

if ($digit ne "") {
open (FILE, ">outfile.txt") || die("cant open outfile\n"); 
print FILE "9   $digit\n";
close(FILE);
}
else
{
    print "No digit found!\n";
}
exit;
```

If you want to get all instances in the infile where your regex matches, the following should do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open (DATA, "</usr/infile")  || die("cant open infile\n");   
open (FILE, ">/usr/outfile") || die("cant open outfile\n"); 

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/\s9\s(\d+)/) #regex to capture digit '234' from ' 9 234' 
    {
       print "Found digit is $1\n"; # 
       print FILE "9   $1\n";
    }
}


close(DATA);
close (FILE);
exit;
```

Comment: @RC: as I said if I do declare it outside then it takes in that value (i.e. the value with which it was declared) and not the value being captured using regex. So what you are suggesting wont work.

Comment: The reason it isn't being captured when you declare it outside is b/c the my $digit; inside your while loop is the one being assigned by the regex, not the global one.  Since the $digit inside the while goes out of scope at the while closing brace, you end up writing to outfile using the global $digit value instead of the one you set in the loop.

Comment: @RC: So is there a way to write $digit to outfile with value it gets captures using regex?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (<DATA>){
    my ($digit)= $_=~ /\s9\s(\d+)/; #regex to capture digit '234' from ' 9 234'
    if ($digit ne ""){
    print "digit is $digit\n"; # this prints fine
    }
}
```

Lexical variables (the ones created with my) exist within the scope they are declared, so $digit is created and destroyed each time through the loop.

Comment: @Chas.Owens: So is there any other way to write $digit to another file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare `$digit` with `my` inside your `while()` loop; declare it just outside:

```
my $digit;
while( <DATA> ) {
    # stuff that sets $digit... 
}

open( FILE , '>out' );
print FILE $digit;
```

Comment: Furthermore, don't use `my ($digit)` inside the loop because that declares *another* variable called `$digit`.

Comment: Right, once you've declared `$digit` *once* with `my`, don't declare it again, just use it. 

@RC, what you're saying happens will happen if you use `my` more than once -- the variable inside the `while` is getting shadowed.

Comment: @genehack: As I mentioned, on doing that the '$digit' bring written to 'out' takes in the value with which it was declared i.e '' and not the one which is captured using regex.

Comment: @shubster post the revised code that you say isn't working then -- at this point there are 3 people (me, Greg, and RC) all telling you the exact same thing, so if you're going to claim it's not working, *show* what you're doing that isn't working -- because from what you've said so far, what all three of us has said is, um, right.

Comment: great, now remove the 'my' from the first line of the `while()` loop, so that it reads:

    while (<DATA>) {
      ($digit) = $_ =~ /blahregexp/;

and see if that doesn't work better. (Chas is right, however, in that $digit may still get stomped on by other lines; RC is right that you should probably just output $digit from inside the loop.)

Comment: @genehack: it does not work. If you know a way to retain the value outside the loop, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `$digits` to be local to the scope of the while loop by using `my`. The `$digit` in the `print` statement is out of scope and that is what is causing the message.

To correct this, declare `my $digit` before the while loop or declare it with `our` instead of `my` to make it global.

I would do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $digit = "None";  # None if there are no digits found

open (DATA, "</usr/infile") || die "cant open infile\n"; #file from digit has to read
while (<DATA>){    
    ($digit) = $_=~ /\s9\s(\d+)/; #regex to capture digit " 9 234"    
    if ($digit ne ""){    
        print "digit is $digit\n"; # this prints fine    
    }
}
open (FILE, ">/usr/outfile") || die "cant open outfile\n"; #file to which digit has to be finally written
print FILE "9   $digit";
close(DATA);
close(FILE);
```

If you did not get a digit, you would get None for the `$digit`.

Hope this helps.